# MySQL ST_Buffer minimum radius

Tags: php, mysql, gis, spatial-query, mysql-spatial

I have a series of polygons stored in a MySQL table that I need to return as exploded polygons which are a minimum of a given distance from the original.

The [ST_Buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer) function performs a very similar function to what I am after however the distance between this polygon and the original must be at least the distance value specified.

[The manual states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer):

> ST_Buffer Returns a geometry that represents all points whose distance from the geometry value g is **less than or equal** to a distance of d

The problem I am facing is the ST_Buffer function is returning polygons which are only being exploded by 2.6nm in places instead of the minimum distance of 3nm I have set

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Buffer(ST_ExteriorRing(boundary),0.05')) AS `extended_boundary` from boundaries'
```

Is there a similar function that guarantees a minimum distance? It doesn't matter if it goes over by a small amount but it must be no less than the distance specified.

**EDIT/Solution:** I ended up creating a Postgres database to solve this with the PostGIS library and the geography data type. It feels like an overkill to run it just for a single table and query but the MySQL library lacks the required functionality.

Comment: Did you tried diferrent buffer strategies in the ST_Buffer function? Such as point_square, end_flat or join_round?

Comment: I did. In the end I swapped the entire thing to use Postgres instead as it was more a function of trying to do spherical calculations with a geometry library rather than a geography one.